# IIS Shared Config override IP address for FTP server in Azure

Tags: iis, azure, ftp

I'm creating a High Available FTPserver in MS Azure.
Setup:

2 VM's, using the recently released regional network, that enables me to use a instance level public ip for for the two VM's, so I'm able to bypass the Azure NLB and this enables me to use passive FTP.

I'm using a DFSshare for the files, AD, IIS Shared config,...

I have a problem with the IIS shared config, it's working smoothly, but now I have to disable the shared config to be able to set the IPadress in IIS. (Both servers have a different public IP).

Would it be possible to use the shared config but override the IP per server? You can't use DNS names in IIS.

http://gyazo.com/f8d78baa42775519361aa1ee51838ba8

I don't know if you can spoof an IP, forward,...? For example I insert 10.0.0.1, but Windows converts it to the public IP I set somewhere on the server? Machine.config,...

Kind Regards,

Brecht

Comment: Duh. This is such a serverfault question. Reading comprehension FTL.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this by using environment variables in my  applicationhost.config (shared config file).  There are 4 steps...

**Step 1** - 
Configure 3 environment variables on EACH server with unique IPs.
%FTP1_IP%=192.168.1.1 / %FTP3_IP%=192.168.1.3 / %FTP3_IP%=192.168.1.5
%FTP1_IP%=192.168.1.2 / %FTP3_IP%=192.168.1.4 / %FTP3_IP%=192.168.1.6

**Step 2** - 
TAKE OWNERSHIP and edit system32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml
You need to add expanded="true" to all places where you see bindinginformation
You need to do this on both FTP servers
(You need to do this because by default IIS only allows variables to be used for file paths)

**Step 3** - 
Edit your bindings in your shared applicationhost.config like this...

binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="%FTP1_IP%:21:"

binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="%FTP2_IP%:21:"

binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="%FTP3_IP%:21:"

**Step 4** - 
REBOOT :)  Now you have a shared configuration file with unique IPs for each server!!